# Java: how to prepare layout for printing

Tags: java

I'm a newbie to Java.

Could you help me understand how to construct printing of a rather complicated report. The report is a table with a lot of fields about a services rendered to a client (date, client, service, signatures etc.). The layout of this table may change in time if the boss orders. 
Printing of the report may be done from many computers to many printers.

What I can't think of is how to cope with this: to pseudographics is outdated and complicated if the layout changes.

The other approach is to use Excel workbooks (or something similar). In this case all I need is putting information in the right cell. This is good because Excell will be responsible for correct printing. But this is a bit more burdensome for the computer and slow for the user: to launch Excell, maybe the user will have to check the borders or something.

Well, could you recommend me anything?

Comment: I would recommend you [JasperReports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JasperReports)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use [JasperReports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library) to generate PDF files.  It's an open source Java library and comes with a [report designer](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio) that easily plugs into Eclipse.  A stand-alone version of the report designer is available, if you use a different IDE.